# Order of Execution in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, trigger, order-of-execution

If you update name of record in both before insert trigger and save method of custom controller.Which one will get updated.I went through this [example](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_lifecycle_example.htm) provided by salesforce.I am getting confused.Can someone explain me the execution order in visualforce page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your triggers will be fired as soon as you use a DML operation in your trigger.

Take this very simple example:

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page controller="CustomController">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!saveObject}" value="Save"/>
</apex:page>
```

**Custom Controller**

```
public class CustomController
{
    public PageRefence saveObject()
    {
        CustomObject__c anObject = new CustomObject__c();
        anObject.CustomField__c = 'Cheese';
        insert anObject;

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger CustomObjectTrigger on CustomObject__c (before insert) 
{
    for(CustomObject anObject : Trigger.new)
    {
        anObject.CustomField__c = 'Bacon';
    }
}
```

In this case the `CustomObject__c` record that has been created will have `'Bacon'` in `CustomField__c` **NOT** `'Cheese'` as it was overwritten by the trigger.

If you don't want this behavior then you can add a checkbox to your object and then check if it is checked or not in your trigger to allow you to bypass it.

Here is an example:

**Custom Controller**

```
public class CustomController
{
    public PageRefence saveLead()
    {
        CustomObject__c anObject = new CustomObject__c();
        anObject.CustomField__c = 'Cheese';
        anObject.AllowAutoUpdate__c = false;
        insert anObject;

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger CustomObjectTrigger on CustomObject__c (before insert) 
{
    for(CustomObject anObject : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(anObject.AllowAutoUpdate__c)
        {
            anObject.CustomField__c = 'Bacon';
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the `CustomObject__c` record that has been created will have `'Cheese'` in `CustomField__c` as it was not overwritten by the trigger since `AllowAutoUpdate__c` was `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The example you looked at explained that order of execution on the visualforce page can't be guaranteed if your code is written in certain ways. The record itself doesn't get updated until you save when using a before insert trigger.